# .NET Multi-thread a background process with a thread limit?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm relatively new to parallel programming and have a need to run a background process on different threads.

The scenario is this - something will cause the first background process to run - it could take up to 45 seconds (for example) to complete.  Meanwhile, at some arbitrary point after the first background process runs, another event occurs which in turn causes the second background process to run - say 20 seconds in.  I don't want to wait 25 more seconds for the first process to complete, I want to get that second process running right away on another thread.  But, I want to also limit the number of threads that can be spurned up.

Do I need to create some sort of queuing class with BackgroundWorker objects or similar?  what would the best approach be for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be to use the Task Parallel Library to accomplish this. Instead of spinning up threads to run your tasks, you would start new tasks using Task.Run(), or something similar.

The Task Parallel Library uses a TaskScheduler to execute your tasks on a thread pool. The TaskScheduler tries to optimize the number of threads in the thread pool to increase throughput. Because the TaskSchedule reuses threads from one task to the next, it is unlikely that you will need to limit the number of threads in the thread pool.

For more information about the TaskScheduler in general see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx

If you are sure that you need to limit the number of threads, you can extend the TaskScheduler class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx

Comment: Note that thread pools are specifically designed for short lived operations; something that is taking 45 seconds to run really shouldn't be put into a thread pool.

Comment: For tasks that you know will take a long time, you can use the TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning flag (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx) to tell the TaskScheduler not to increase the number of threads in the thread pool because of that task. In my experience though I would probably not consider 45 seconds to be a long running task, especially if this is the upper limit of how long your tasks are expected to take.

Comment: The current implementation will always create a new Thread, rather than using the thread pool, when the `LongRunning` option is specified.  (Granted that's subject to change of course.)  The idea is that for short tasks the overhead of creating a new thread is large compared to the task itself, thus greatly reducing throughput.  In this case though a task of 20-45 seconds is so much larger than the time spent creating a new thread that this is not a particularly significant overhead, hence not using the thread pool is fine.